# Bug or feature? If statement inside double integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, mathematica

Generally speaking,

$$ \int_c^a f(x) dx = \int_c^{a-b} f(x) dx + \int_{a-b}^a f(x) dx$$

However, consider the following Mathematica code:
[image: Code]

So apparently, the sum of the two sub-integrals $1/32 + 0 = 1/32$ does not equal the base-integral $-3/32$.

Am I invoking the functions in a wrong way? Should I not use If statements inside integrals?

Comment: This may be better suited for the mathematica stackexchange

Comment: So to see if I understand right: $h(x)=1$ if $0<x<1$ and $h(x)=0$ else? And similar for $i[y]$?

Comment: The last integral goes from $a-b$ to $1$, but instead should go to $a$.

Comment: @Stef yes that's correct (with weak inequalities, not strict).

Comment: The piecewise defined functions are unimportant here, since on the intervals in question all functions equal 1.

Comment: @vadim123 you are right; however I set $a=1$, so doesn't matter in that particular case.

Comment: @vadim123, no, for $x \in [a-b,1]$, the inner integral is $0$ (as the last piecewase integral shows).

Comment: Ok I moved it there: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103027/bug-or-feature-if-statement-inside-double-integrals

So please close the question here; sorry for posting wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

The first integral is clearly false. You cannot integrate non-negative functions and get a negative result. (Moreover I believe that this is a joint pdf and you are trying to calculate the probability $P(Y>X+1/2)$. Did I find it?)

The problem is that the program puts $$i[y]=1$$ for all $x+1/2<y<1$ which is obviously not correct, since at some point $x+1/2$ exceeds $1$ and $i[y]$ must become zero (exactly at the point $b=1/2$ where you split later). So, the problem is that the program does not evaluate correctly $i[y]$ in the first case. Perhaps it is this with the *if statement inside the integrals* that you say yourself. When you split later in $1/4$ to $1/2$ and $1/2$ to $1$ you get the correct result.

Comment: Well spotted! In fact it's $P(X > 1/4 \land Y > X + 1/2$), hence the first integral. Yes I know how to calculate it and that the split version is the correct one; the question is why the way I invoke it in Mathematica gets it wrong.

Comment: @bonifaz Yes, there is some problem with the if statement inside the integral. Interesting. You better ask in a programming site. Concerning the mathematical formulation, I do not see any mistake.